# Как создать страницу записей?

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование

У меня имеется сайт на Wordpress.
`front-page.php` - главная страница
page.php - страницы about, contact и тд
`single.php` - определенный пост

Так же я хочу создать страницу posts в ней я хочу вывести все посты. Не могу понять, как создать? Создал страницу archive внутри wordpress, в настройках выбрал эту страницу, так же у меня файл `archive.php` есть, в нем я вывожу все посты, но ничего не работает, тупо пустая страница, даже шапка не выводится. Расскажите пожалуйста, как создать страницу постов, расскажите по шагам, что создавать, что делать и тд.

Answer (score 0):

> Так же я хочу создать страницу posts в ней я хочу вывести все посты.

Для вывода всех записей нужно создать пустую страницу и назначить её для блока в настройках чтения.

[image]

*А страницы `posts` не бывает.*